# not parsing PHP JSON

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I am not sure if i have a problem with my JSON or with my code in xcode, but i cannot get xcode to parse my JSON. My JSON is valid however I cannot get it to parse. Anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Here is my PHP for generating JSON:

```
 $channel['items']['post']['category_name'][$category_name]['details'][] = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'description' => $description,
    'category_id' => $category_id,

    );
}   
$channels = array($channel);
$json = json_encode($channel);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

Which gives JSON like this:

```
{

"items": {

    "post": {

        "category_name": {

            "Baby": {

                "details": [

                    {

                        "title": "trying with category id again",

                        "price": "3344.55",

                          },



                    {

                        "title": "this is sending with description ",

                        "price": "900000.00",

                    }

                ]

            },

            “Other Baby Stuff": {

                "details": [

                    {

                        "title": "putting in title",

                        "price": "3000.99",
```

Here is my code in xcode to parse (i want my section headers the category name like "Baby", "Other Baby Stuff", etc:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [m_tableView reloadData];

});
_buyCategory =  json[@"items"][@"post"][@"category_name"];//THIS IS PARSING JUST FINE NOW
NSLog(@"Items: %@", _buyCategory);
NSLog(@"Array Count: %u", [_buyCategory count]);

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (appDelegate.bLoadBuy == 1) {
    NSString *section = [[_buyCategory allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]; ///NOT RETURNING ANYTHING
    NSLog(@"category: %@", section); //I AM NOT EVEN GETTING NSLOG HERE

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",section];];
```

And in my tableview cell (i want my details)

```
_buyTitle = [[tempResults objectForKey:@"details"] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Comment: Where did you parse the JSON? What exactly is your data which you want to display? The given JSON is a "JSON Object" (aka a dictionary, hash, associative container, etc.) which is not appropriate for being displayed in a table view. A table view wants an *array* of objects.

Comment: thank you for your help. I want to pass that into my table view. The JSON repeats for many different categories. The one above just shows Baby, but i have other categories like Baby Clothes, etc. So each category name should be a section name in my table with the details (title, etc) in the cell in the table.

Comment: Now, for the sections, this makes sense. But did you probably meant, each detail entry should be displayed in a cell (separate row), as opposed to *all* details in *one* cell?

Comment: oh yeah all details in one cell (not really all details...only some and the rest will be in my detail screen) but i think you get what i mean.

Comment: See chuthan20's answer. ;)

Comment: Bit confused about how _tableData is getting populated because you just assigned _buyCategory in fetchedData method. Also when you say '//I AM NOT EVEN GETTING NSLOG HERE' do you mean the program doesn't even execute that NSLog or it is executing but only outputs 'category: ' without any section because section is nil?

Comment: Its not even executing NSLog there. Sorry, so my code was just bad cut and paste. I have updated now to be correct, and it is parsing the JSON. I'm just not getting anything in my section header code...not even NSLog.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *category = json[@"items"][@"post"][@"category_name"];

//section title
NSString *section = [[category allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]

//array of detail object..  so details[0][@"title"] should give you the first titme
NSArray *details = [category objectForKey:section];
```

Comment: OKay, thank you. I am trying this. Are you saying this goes into titleforheaderinsection?

Comment: NSString *section..// <-  you should return this section string inside titleForHeaderInSection method. That should contain the word 'Baby'.

Comment: okay, i'm with you. Unfortunately my wife is making me go shopping. i will try this in a little while. thank you for you help!

Comment: `[[category allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]` will return an arbitrary item, not necessarily "Baby" since dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: Yea, since he doesn't have an array to keep the order, I just went with index 0 to show him as an example. Of course I was wrong to say it will return 'Baby' as the value but from the sample json that was posted, it was easier say 'Baby' will be the value.

Comment: I am still struggling with this. I have updated my code above to show the entire function for fetched data. I probably was not giving enough info before. I am now able to parse my JSON but I am not able to figure out how to get the sections and details. thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I also gave more of my JSON to better illustrate what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Updated again. I got further with the suggested code changes. I'm parsing now into buyCategory but my section titles are not printing.